# Android: CustomAdapter ArrayList data Nullpointerexception

Tags: android, json, listview, nullpointerexception, adapter

I have been learning android app development for two weeks and really got stuck here. I attempted to retrieve hourly-forecast data (which is in JSON format) from OpenWeatherMap API in a ArrayList that can be fitted into a Listview with three elements by a customised Adapter. If the user enter a city name, s/he should be able to see a list - weather information per hour occupies one line of the list. The data retrieval process was done by AsyncTask.

However after hitting the "find sun" button, the app crashed and the logcat kept showing me:

```
>FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'RowAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference
>at MainActivity$WeatherDownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:78)
>at MainActivity$WeatherDownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:61)
>at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
>at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
>at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
>at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Line 61 is    public class WeatherDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Weather>> "\n"
Line 78 is    for (Weather w : weather) {rowAdapter.add(w);}
```

This is my Main Activity java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private RowAdapter rowAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Weather> data = new ArrayList<Weather>();
    ListView listv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
    RowAdapter rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
    listv.setAdapter(rowAdapter);
}

public void handleClick(View v) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Search Button handled");
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityname);
    String searchTerm = text.getText().toString();

    WeatherDownloadTask task = new WeatherDownloadTask();
    task.execute(searchTerm);
}

public class WeatherDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Weather>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Weather> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            ArrayList<Weather> data = WeatherDownloader.downloadWeather(params[0]);
            Log.d(TAG, data.toString());
            return data;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Weather> weather) {
            super.onPostExecute(weather);
            rowAdapter.clear();
            for (Weather w : weather) {
                rowAdapter.add(w);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code to download data from the API:

```
public class WeatherDownloader {
private static String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
private static String IMG_URL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/";

// returns ArrayList of Weather, rather than String[]
public static ArrayList<Weather> downloadWeather(String location) throws JSONException {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    ArrayList<Weather> weather = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(BASE_URL + location + "&units=metric" +
                "&APPID=" + BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY)).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream == null) return null;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        String results = buffer.toString();

        weather = parseWeatherJSON(results);
        if (weather == null) weather = new ArrayList<Weather>();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            con.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return weather;
}


/**
 * Parses a JSON String into a list of Weather objects
 */
public static ArrayList<Weather> parseWeatherJSON(String json) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<Weather> weather = new ArrayList<Weather>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    Weather item = new Weather();

    JSONArray JSONArray_weather = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");

    for (int i = 0; i < JSONArray_weather.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject JSONObject_weather = JSONArray_weather.getJSONObject(i);
        item.setSun(JSONObject_weather.getString("main"));// get the weather description

        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
        String timestr = df.format(new Date(jsonObject.getLong("dt") * 1000));
        item.setTime(timestr); // get the time;

        // key = "main"
        JSONObject JSONObject_main = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");
        item.setTemperature(JSONObject_main.getDouble("temp")); // get the temperature;

        weather.add(item);
        }
    return weather;
    }
}
```

This is the Adapter class:

```
public class   RowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather> {

private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<Weather> data;
private final int resource;

// a constructor
public RowAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Weather> data) {
    super(context, resource, data);
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_item,parent,false);

    // initialize the components

        holder.textView1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sun);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.textView3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.temp);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Weather weather = data.get(position);

    holder.textView1.setText(weather.getSun());
    holder.textView2.setText(weather.getTime());
    holder.textView3.setText(String.valueOf(weather.getTemperature()));
    return row;
}
static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textView3;
}
}
```

The Main Activity xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainactivity"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cityname"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:hint="City..."
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Find Sun"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="handleClick"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sunornot"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text = "Will there be sun?"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0.22"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cityname"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weather_icon"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weather_icon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listv"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listv"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sunornot" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am totally new to app development, I know there might be many stupid mistakes. But I even don't know how to debug properly. It will be very kind of you to give me some suggestions. All help are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onCreate() of Main Activity

change

```
RowAdapter rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
```

to

```
rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt answer! Yes it worked, but my project gives further error warnings. Could you take a look at the Adapter Class file? The logcat says 'NullpointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.widget.TextView RowAdapter$ViewHolder.textView1' on a null object reference'.

Comment: add holder = new Holder() in  if (convertView == null) {} in Adapter class.

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much! Got the result I wanted. Seems similar to the mistake I made in the main activity file : P

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem

```
RowAdapter rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
```

You must remove ***RowAdapter*** to

```
rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
```

Try this!!!!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private RowAdapter rowAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ArrayList<Weather> data = new ArrayList<Weather>();
ListView listv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
listv.setAdapter(rowAdapter);
}

public void handleClick(View v) {
Log.v(TAG, "Search Button handled");
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityname);
String searchTerm = text.getText().toString();

WeatherDownloadTask task = new WeatherDownloadTask();
task.execute(searchTerm);
}

public class WeatherDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Weather>> {

@Override
protected ArrayList<Weather> doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        ArrayList<Weather> data = WeatherDownloader.downloadWeather(params[0]);
        Log.d(TAG, data.toString());
        return data;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Weather> weather) {
        super.onPostExecute(weather);
        rowAdapter.clear();
        for (Weather w : weather) {
            rowAdapter.add(w);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mistake :**

You have already declared  `private RowAdapter rowAdapter;` in declaration part.

Though again you have declared and initialize

```
RowAdapter rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
listv.setAdapter(rowAdapter);
```

so change it to

```
rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
listv.setAdapter(rowAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Declare  `ArrayList<Weather> data = new ArrayList<Weather>();` Outside the method and change `onPostExecute` Method

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Weather> weather) {
                super.onPostExecute(weather);
                data.clear();

                for (Weather w : weather) {
                    data.add(w);
                }
              RowAdapter rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
             listv.setAdapter(rowAdapter);
            }
        }
```

Hope your problem solved.

Comment: I think I did declare it at the beginning of the main activity file. Do you mean I should declare it right before the PostExecute Method or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, because you don't have ArrayList<Weather> data value in beginning of the Main Activity. so you have to declare onPostExecute Method.

Answer (score 0):

remove the local declartion of adapter because you already declared it globally.

```
rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in declaring and initializing `rowAdapter`, replace below line

```
 RowAdapter rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
```

with

```
rowAdapter = new RowAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.weather_item, data);
```

**Why** : because `rowAdapter` is a global variable which you never initialized and creating one more local variable with same name in `onCreate` method.